# What is the name of this component?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, terminology, dell-studio

I was wondering what the name of the 5th component was. 
[image]

Dell 1747 Studio 17

Comment: You took the image from page 20 of the manual Joel quoted and asked here instead of reading two pages further?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to pages 20 and 21 of the pdf located [here](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/studio1747/en/sg/sg_en.pdf), it's the battery status light.

Answer (score 1):

Based on position, either a charging LED?  What make/model of laptop do you have?  It should be listed in the user's guide.

Comment: Dell 1747 Studio 17